# How to avoid page refresh for laravel default pagination

Tags: php, laravel-5, pagination

I'm using `laravel` Default pagination and sending data to view page using the code below,

```
$main_category = pep_bank_maincategory1::select('main_cat_id','main_cat_name')->where('status',0)->paginate(10);
return view('sompage')->with('main_category',$main_category);
```

In my blade I'm displaying it using the code.

```
 {!! $main_category->render() !!}
```

I'm displaying it successfully but the page get refreshed when I click next   button how to avoid it. Below is my object which I'm rendering in view page.

```
{"total":43,"per_page":10,"current_page":1,"last_page":5,
  "next_page_url":"http:\/\/localhost:8000\/launch\/?page=2","prev_page_url":null,"from":1,
  "to":10,"data":[{"main_cat_id":1,"main_cat_name":"Agriculture"},
  {"main_cat_id":2,"main_cat_name":"Apparel"},
  {"main_cat_id":3,"main_cat_name":"Automobiles & Motorcycles"},
  {"main_cat_id":4,"main_cat_name":"Business Services"},
  {"main_cat_id":5,"main_cat_name":"Chemicals"}, 
  {"main_cat_id":6,"main_cat_name":"Computer Hardware & Software"},
  {"main_cat_id":7,"main_cat_name":"Construction & Real Estate"},
  {"main_cat_id":8,"main_cat_name":"Consumer Electronics"},
  {"main_cat_id":9,"main_cat_name":"Electrical Equipments"},
  {"main_cat_id":10,"main_cat_name":"Electronic Components"}]}
```

Comment: thanks StepUp for your edit

Answer (score 0):

you can try this below code.hope it works.

```
{!!  $main_category->appends(Input::except('page'))->render() !!}
```